# How to prevent content from being pushed down on appearance of floating menu in mobile display

Tags: css, menu, floating

Issue: Upon appearance of floating menu in mobile browsers, a large chunk of content is pushed down leaving white space upon the first appearance of the floating menu.

Go to **deleted** in a mobile browser or using the usual developer's mobile emnulator to see the issue. Scroll down and when the menu floats, the content is pushed down leaving a large white space.

How can I fix this? Looking for help from the CSS ninjas. Thank you :)

Edit: this issue arises with using WP plugin myStickymenu on mobile browsers. The answer has been indicated below, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Your javascript seems to add a `height: 718px` property to the `div#mysticky-wrap` as soon as you scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a max-height of 61px (the height of your sticky wrap) to `#mysticky-wrap`, it should fix your issue.

```
#mysticky-wrap {
   max-height: 61px !important;
}
```